# stylePreprocessorOptions angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components) to add importable scss files through stylePreprocessorOptions in Angular 8 but I keep getting the error that it is not being found. Any input is apreciated, this neat trick is very useful!

below is my angular.json

```css
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "thebearcottages-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/thebearcottages-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styling/"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "thebearcottages-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "thebearcottages-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "thebearcottages-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "thebearcottages-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "thebearcottages-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "thebearcottages-app"
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> ERROR in ./src/app/content-component/gallery/gallery.component.scss
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> @import "grid";
>          ^
>         Can't find stylesheet to import.
>     ╷
>   1 │ @import "grid";
>     │         ^^^^^^
>     ╵
>     stdin 1:9  root stylesheet
>         in /Users/konstantinurban/Desktop/thebearcottages/src/app/content-component/gallery/gallery.component.scss (line 1, column 9)

Comment: It started working out of the blue, can't tell what changed!

Comment: any idea what changes did you make,  if any or any dependencies upgrades?

Comment: Any luck with this, really would like to have this working?

Comment: @EdgarQuintero make sure its under `roots` and not `test`

Answer (score 9):

I found same bug when started new app with Angular 8.
It says "Can't find stylesheet to import." even for properly declared imports. After small investigation i found that it is related to sass-loader bug https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/704
I hope it will be fixed soon, but meanwhile there is a workaround:

For existing `_mixins.scss` in your stylePreprocessorOptions / includePaths, use filename including first underscore

```
@import '_mixins';
```

instead of more pretty, but currently buggy

```
@import 'mixins';
```

Answer (score 5):

Please checkout your paths once again. In my case the problem was solved by including `src` like this:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/assets/styles",
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that if you use scss when you import as prefix you need specify type.
@import "colors.scss";

Answer (score 1):

Too many people are having this issue.

Seems that we need to add :

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [

            "// here paths to include"
            "assets/styles",
          ]
```

It seems to solve some issues, but still doesn't resolved me compass imports.

Comment: You can edit the answer you provided to include the typo mentioned in comment