# imported sass files in styles.scss are not found

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

Angular can't find my sass files.

Here's a sample error whenever i run `ng serve`

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--17!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Failed to find 'variables'
  in [
    /home/chan-dev/Coding/angular/theme-switcher-demo/src
  ]
    at /home/chan-dev/Coding/angular/theme-switcher-demo/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13
    at async LazyResult.runAsync (/home/chan-dev/Coding/angular/theme-switcher-demo/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:331:11)
    at async Object.loader (/home/chan-dev/Coding/angular/theme-switcher-demo/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:94:14)
```

---

Here's my directory structure.

```
.
└── src/
    ├── app
    ├── assets
    ├── environments
    ├── styles/
    │   ├── _theme.scss
    │   └── _variables.scss
    └── styles.scss
```

---

styles.scss content

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import 'variables';
@import 'theme';
```

---

Already added `includePaths` in `angular.json`.
Note that my angular.json uses `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser`.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "theme-switcher-demo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineTemplate": true,
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/theme-switcher-demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/styles"]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "theme-switcher-demo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "theme-switcher-demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "theme-switcher-demo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "theme-switcher-demo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "theme-switcher-demo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "theme-switcher-demo"
}
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: @xingkong, the workaround i did was to import with underscore and file extension. So if you want to import partial.scss then just do `@import _partial.scss`.

There seems to be a bug with partials. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58152757/9732932)

Comment: Thanks @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer, I found the solution for this. It was missing the sass-load. I will put the details in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am having the exact same issue and assuming you are adding tailwind into the angular project.

It turns out the root cause is the custom webpack config for tailwind. problem solved after I added the additional sass-loader to the scss files. Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {

              postcssOptions: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                ident: 'postcss',
                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                plugins: [
                  require('postcss-import'),
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader' // This is the fix
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using Tailwind, but your code helped me to setup PostCSS in a Angular 11 project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may be a duplicate of [stylePreprocessorOptions angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164159/stylepreprocessoroptions-angular-8)

Instead of adding your path, you could always make a `src/styles/index.scss` and import your styles:

```
@import "_theme.scss";
@import "_variables.scss";
```

Then add it to your `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` style list.

Comment: thanks,  followed your answer, but it still the same result. Regardless if i import names using the following formats `_nameOfFile.scss` or without underscore `nameOfFile.scss`.