# Issues compiling and including SCSS in Nx publishable libraries

Tags: angular, sass, nrwl-nx

I have created a style library in our Nx Workspace with the `--publishable` flag. This is because we will need to publish the styles as an npm package to use the styles in other products that aren't in our Nx Workspace.

I have done this previously using a `webpack.config.js` but am trying to do this via the Nx commands.

When I run the Nx:build command it doesn't include the scss files (as expected). To get round this, I tried:

##### Attempts to make it work

I added this to the `angular.json` file in `project/{{lib-project}}/architect/build/options`

```json
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/style-paths"
  ]
}
```

This fails with the message:

```
———————————————————————————————————————————————

> nx run shared-ui:build:development --watch 
'stylePreprocessorOptions' is not found in schema

———————————————————————————————————————————————
```

Trying this with the styles or assets tags give me the same warnings.

It appears these work when the `projectType` is `application` but fails when it is `library`.

Why are these errors happening when according to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#complex-configuration-values) there is no mention of these being `projectType` specific.

Any help with how are you meant to compile the SCSS files without these commands in Nx?

### TL;DR

I want to create a publishable styles lib to push to npm but it's unclear how to compile and move the SCSS, without using `webpack`, to the generated dist folder.

Comment: whats part is not working for you ? can you explain in simple short way ?

Comment: I can’t get my SCSS files (or compiled CSS files) to appear in the generated dist folder. Any way I add them to the angular.json file causes errors at build time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164159/stylepreprocessoroptions-angular-8 may be this link helpful to you

Comment: That references a projectType of application again though, which works already. It's when the projectType is library that it doesn't work.

Comment: @BrenGunning did you find solution for your problem ?